# Legibility of text on a transparent background

Tags: ios, blur, uivibrancyeffect

I wonder how to deal with legibility issues on a blurred background.

The transparent design of the iPhone widget looks really nice. I wanted to reproduce the same feels on my project.

I first tried off putting white letters on a black-tinted background without vibrancy. It did not produce the result I wanted: The white color didn't look natural.

I tried once again, only this time with vibrancy. 
That got me only half-way: The letters are not legible.
You can see the difference between the screenshots below.

I found that a lots of sample projects that feature blurred background didn't deal with this issue.

I wonder if there is a good reference regarding this issue?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Of course they match each other.

Comment: I see, it's like that, is it? Okay, I'm going to stop helping.

Answer (score 0):

There's an excellent reference for this issue.

https://www.omnigroup.com/developer/how-to-make-text-in-a-uivisualeffectview-readable-on-any-background